# Strange sentence in The Guest Cat

Tags: reading-comprehension, literature

I am reading Takashi Hiraide's The Guest Cat and I am stuck on the following passage.

> 前夜はめずらしく玄関から入ってきたので、 専用の出入口を、 ついうっかり閉め たままにしていたのである。
>
> 以後、「チビちゃんの望郷」とそれを呼んで、 世間的にもめずらしいだろう姿をたびたび思い出した。
>
> やはりうちの猫ではないのだ、ということを、 妻は別のしかたで知らされている。

I have problem with

> 世間的にもめずらしいだろう姿をたびたび思い出した。

How I should  understand it? My attempt is: "I often remembered form/appearance which was uncommon even in society/world." Thank you for any help.

Comment: 「前夜はめずらしく玄関から入ってきたので」より前に、「以後、『チビちゃんの望郷』と**それ**を呼んで、」の「それ」が指すもの（=猫の姿を描写した箇所）があると思うので、もう少し前の部分を引用してもらえませんか？

Answer (score 1):

I cannot tell from your excerpt what exactly それ refers to, but it is probably a peculiar way this cat behaved when it couldn’t enter the house one day because the cat flap was closed. Whatever it was like, there must have been something to it that made the speaker think it is uncommon, and he believes it is uncommon by the standards of 世間 (ordinary people in general), too.

世間的にもめずらしいだろう modifies the noun 姿 as an adjectival (or “relative”) clause. Judging from your translation attempt, I think you got this right.

Translating も as “even” is not bad, either. The speaker thinks it is uncommon even by the standards of 世間, not only in his own judgment.

だろう adds the sense of “probably” because the speaker cannot be completely sure if 世間 agree it is uncommon.

If your doubt is about 世間, it’s not a very easy word to translate. Here, it refers to society in general, or people that compose it, as opposed to the speaker as an individual.